# Remove Google Maps Completely from Prestashop 1.6

Tags: api, google-maps, prestashop

Since I am not using the built-in Google Maps functionality in **PrestaShop 1.6**, I was wondering is it possible to completely remove Google Maps scripts from loading in the front-end? There are couple of **.js** files loading form maps.google.com and the slow my page load time. Is it possible to remove this files from loading completely?

[Here is link to my store.](https://store.dji.bg/en/)
[Here is a screenshot with the .js files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra0dV.png)

Answer (score 0):

`PS 1.6` with `default-bootstrap` theme only adds Google Maps JS in the Stores front controller page:

```
public function setMedia()
{
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'stores.css');

    if (!Configuration::get('PS_STORES_SIMPLIFIED')) {
        $api_key = (Configuration::get('PS_API_KEY')) ? 'key=' . Configuration::get('PS_API_KEY') . '&' : '';
        $default_country = new Country((int)Tools::getCountry());
        $this->addJS('http'.((Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE')) ? 's' : '').'://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?'.$api_key.'region='.substr($default_country->iso_code, 0, 2));
        $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'stores.js');
    }
}
```

So your problem is related with your theme or with a module.

I'd recommend you to download all the files in your local drive and make a global search in all files for the string `maps.google.com'. Then you will see who's attaching Google Maps JS in your store.

Comment: So, I have checked every tpl file on the server and there was no **maps.google.com** string. Is it OK to just remove the line `$this->addJS('http'.((Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED') && Configuration::get('PS_SSL_ENABLED_EVERYWHERE')) ? 's' : '').'://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?'.$api_key.'region='.substr($default_country->iso_code, 0, 2));` from the StoresController.php

Comment: @TEMPEX not only TPL but PHP or even JS.